# Script enqueue in wordpress dont work

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm developing a plugin in wordpress, this plugin have a custom post and I want to add datepicker script to a metabox. I have tried to enqueue my scripts this way, but it seems it doesn't work cause those scripts are not loaded

```
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'functions.php');

function chahadat_scripts()
{
    wp_register_script( 'imagelightbox.js', plugins_url( 'js/imagelightbox.js', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script(  'imagelightbox.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'imagelightbox.min.js', plugins_url( 'js/imagelightbox.min.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_script(  'imagelightbox.min.js' );
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js', array(jquery), 3.3, true);
    wp_register_script('jqueryui', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js', array(jquery), 3.3, true);
    wp_register_style('jqueryuistyle', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css', 3.3, true);
    wp_register_script( 'dates', plugins_url( 'js/date.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_script(  'dates' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chahadat_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below working code.Use both constant of define method in main file of plugin if possible.cross check your plugin url inside function after paste code by "echo CHAHADAT_PLUGIN_PLUGIN_URL"

```
 define('CHAHADAT_PLUGIN', __FILE__);
 define('CHAHADAT_PLUGIN_PLUGIN_URL', untrailingslashit(plugins_url('', CHAHADAT_PLUGIN)));

function chahadat_scripts()
{
    wp_register_script( 'imagelightbox.js', CHAHADAT_PLUGIN_PLUGIN_URL.'/js/imagelightbox.js');
    wp_enqueue_script(  'imagelightbox.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'imagelightbox.min.js', CHAHADAT_PLUGIN_PLUGIN_URL.'/js/imagelightbox.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script(  'imagelightbox.min.js' );
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js', array(jquery), 3.3, true);
    wp_register_script('jqueryui', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js', array(jquery), 3.3,          true);
    wp_register_style('jqueryuistyle', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css', 3.3,         true);
    wp_register_script( 'dates', CHAHADAT_PLUGIN_PLUGIN_URL.'/js/date.js');
    wp_enqueue_script(  'dates' );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chahadat_scripts' );
```

Comment: thank you but this doesn't work, i have to mention that im trying to use datepicker script inside wordpress dashboard

Comment: then replace 'wp_enqueue_scripts' with 'admin_enqueue_scripts' alco check page source and check js is being loaded or not,

Comment: i did but now im getting this error `TypeError: jQuery(...).datepicker is not a function` and my date.js containt this only `jQuery(document).ready(function(  ) {
jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});`

Comment: may be jQuery loading twice in your case..deregister one js if double.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery dependent script libraries has be added this way:

```
function chahadat_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'imagelightbox.js', 
         CHAHADAT_PLUGIN_PLUGIN_URL.'/js/imagelightbox.js', 
         array( 'jquery' ), 
         '1.0.0', 
         true 
     );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chahadat_scripts' );
```

To learn more [Official Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)